# IBM MQ get count of connections grouped by channel name

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm trying to get some monitoring information about user's connections from IBM MQ like this:

```
Connection Name | Channel Name | MCA User | Handel Status
```

Or something like

```
Connection Name | Channel Name | MCA User | Handel Status: N Active, M Inactive
```

by using IBM PCF. But can't understand how to retrieve this info. I can find by connection id handle state with handle_info type and mca user, channel and connection name with info_conn headers. But can't undertsand how to link all this information together this mininun PCF requests.

Comment: When you say Connection name, do you mean the IP that is connecting to the channel or do you mean the CONN id which is a string representing HEX numbers?

Comment: Post the code you have and we'll have a look.  Also, I have posted lots of Java PCF examples on my blog and you should look at my open source project MQ Channel Monitor.

Comment: Your second example suggests "N Active and M Inactive". You can't count inactive connections. There is no state for an inactive connection. There are both zero and an infinite number of connections not currently active.  What information did you want about inactive connections?